# How to get like count for a specific country?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, global, facebook-page

Per [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/19/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/), country-level stats are now provided via the Insights connection on pages.

Unfortunately, those country-level stats only provide data for the top 45 countries. Is there a way to get stats for a specific country?

As an example, Dove has 5 specific country pages. I can currently get the like count for each specific page using the [global_brand_like_count value](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Dove?fields=global_brand_children.fields%28likes,global_brand_like_count,name,new_like_count,username,location,current_location%29,likes,name), but according to the documentation, that field is going away.

One of Dove's country-specific pages is for Switzerland, but that country isn't listed in the country-specific Insights stats because it's not in the top 45, but I would like to be able to get the like count for that specific country.

Answer (score 4):

It seems we have the same problem, not getting likes and talking about count for regional(country) specific pages belonging to a global page.

The global_brand_like_count metric is going away in a week or so, and I am not sure if there is a fairly good replacement available if you do not have an insight access(access to the private data) to the specific page. With this access you could use the page_fans metric.

I fear you have misunderstood a bit regarding the list of countries provided by the page_fans_country metric. The description Facebook provides for this metric is:
"Aggregated Facebook location data, sorted by country, about the people who like your Page"
To put that in an example, for Dove Switzerland's regional page it provides you with the list of top countries that have liked the page, or rather number by users by country. In reality it is only 9 at the moment, but if there where people from 58 countries that have liked this regional page, Facebook would only provided the top 45.
And it gives back the to 45 countries, if there are that many.

To get the lifetime likes(page fans) for a regional page, one idea would be to sum all numbers in the returned list. The only problem is when it is users from more than 45 countries that have liked the page, you would get a incorrect lower number.